# how to catch jquery datatable server side data source parameters in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I'm using [jQuery Datatable](https://www.datatables.net/) and [server side proccessing](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) as data source in my ASP.Net MVC application.
I need to apply search term in my query but I don't know how to catch it.

**here is short version of my controller :**

```
public JsonResult Index(POFilter m) {
   return Json(new {
      data = data,
      ...
   })
}
```

**POFilter.cs**

```
public class POFilter
{
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public List<DT_Order> order { get; set; }
    public string[] search { get; set; }

    public POFilter()
    {
        start = 0;
        length = 10;
        draw = 1;
    }
}

public class DT_Order
{
    public int column { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }
}
```

but for some reason the `search property` is always null. you can see the parameters which are passed by jquery datatable:

```
order[0][column]:0
order[0][dir]:desc
start:0
length:10
search[value]:my search term
search[regex]:false
```

how can I get `my search term` from passed parameters?

Comment: `order` is also null?

Comment: @adricadar no it's not null itself but `order[0].column` and `order[0].dir` have wrong values.
anyway, I found the answer. I should use `m.search = Request["search[value]"]` or in general `Request[key]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *datatables.mvc5* nuget package to get typed modelbinder:

```
public JsonResult GetData([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] IDataTablesRequest requestModel)
{
    // requestModel.Start..
    // requestModel.Length..
    // requestModel.Columns..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an object to hold the search result. Instead of using:

```
public string[] search { get; set; }
```

I use:

```
public DataTableSearch Search { get; set; }
```

Where DataTableSearch is defined as:

```
public class DataTableSearch
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Regex { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know if that doesn't fix your issue (if you're still having an issue).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project, it is a MVC / Jquery datatable implementation made by a friend. 
I use this in almost all of my projects

https://github.com/amoerie/generic-datatables

its a bit hard to implement, but once it is in place, its easy to work with